# Graph: question on planar graph.

Tags: graph-theory

I have a lemma that say:

Let $G$ be a planar graph whose exterior face is bounded by a cycle $u_1,...,u_k$. Then there is a vertex $u_i$ ($i\neq 1,k$) not adjacent to any $u_j$ other than $u_{i-1}$ and $u_{i+1}$.

But for example $K_4$ is planar and this condition doesn't look satisfy. So I don't really understand this lemma.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is written, the graph $K_4$ does satisfy the lemma.

Below I have a planar representation of $K_4$. The exterior face is bounded by the cycle $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$. Here we have $k=3$, and then a vertex $u_i$, such that $i\neq 1, k$, has to be $u_2$. Note how this vertex is not adjacent to any $u_i$ other than $u_1$ and $u_3$.

The key point is of course that the fourth (unnamed) vertex of $K_4$ is not part of the bounding cycle of the exterior face.

[image]

EDIT: Here's the usual planar representation of $K_4$. In this representation, it is easier to see that the fourth vertex does not take part in the cycle bounding the exterior face. The lemma concerns the vertices $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_k$, but these consist only of the vertices of your graph $G$ that bound the exterior face. Notice how the center vertex is not part of the bounding cycle, and thus the lemma does not concern this vertex.
[image]

Also, here's your other example (you had the vertex $v_3$ in two places, so I changed one of them to $v_2$). Notice how the exterior face is bounded by the vertices $v_3$, $v_4$, and $v_5$. Thus, if you let $u_1=v_3$, $u_2=v_4$, and $u_3=v_5$, then the lemma says something about the cycle $u_1,u_2,u_3$, but nothing about the remaining vertices.
[image]

Comment: Sorry to reload the question, but how would you do such this thing with the graph that I just have put on my post ?

Comment: And actually in you picture $u_3$ and $u_2$ are adjacent to $u_4$ (but you did right $u_4$). I'm sorry but I don't understand the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, but the fourth vertex is not part of the cycle bounding the exterior face. I am editing my post to include the more usual planar representation of $K_4$, and have also included your new example as well. Maybe this will clear things up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem in you two other example (take for example $K_4$), $u_1,u_2$ and $u_3$ are all adjacent to $u_4$, no ?

Comment: @idm The point is that there is no $u_4$. The lemma says "...exterior face is bounded by a cycle $u_1,\ldots,u_k$." The fourth vertex of $K_4$ is not part of the cycle that bounds the exterior face. You only use the $u_i$ to denote the vertices of the cycle that bound the exterior face, and all other vertices are not part of this cycle. Let me know, if it makes sense.